# Print python List in subclass

Tags: python

I have a superclass as below:

```
class Container(object):
    """ Holds hashable objects. Objects may occur 0 or more times """
    def __init__(self):
        """ Creates a new container with no objects in it. I.e., any object 
            occurs 0 times in self. """
        self.vals = {}
    def insert(self, e):
        """ assumes e is hashable
            Increases the number times e occurs in self by 1. """
        try:
            self.vals[e] += 1
        except:
            self.vals[e] = 1
    def __str__(self):
        s = ""
        for i in sorted(self.vals.keys()):
            if self.vals[i] != 0:
                s += str(i)+":"+str(self.vals[i])+"\n"
        return s
```

And I worked on a subclass:

```
class Bag(Container):
    def remove(self, e):
        """ assumes e is hashable
            If e occurs in self, reduces the number of 
            times it occurs in self by 1. Otherwise does nothing. """
        # write code here
        if e in self.vals.keys():
            self.vals[e] -= 1

    def count(self, e):
        """ assumes e is hashable
            Returns the number of times e occurs in self. """
        # write code here
        if e not in self.vals.keys():
            return 0
        else:
            return self.vals[e]

    def __add__(self, other):
        new_dict = other.vals
        for e in self.vals.keys():
            if e in other.vals.keys():
                new_dict[e] += self.vals[e]
            else:
                new_dict[e] = self.vals[e]
        return new_dict

    def __str__(self):
        s1 = ""
        for i in sorted(self.new_dict.keys()):
            s1 += str(i)+":"+str(self.new_dict[i])+"\n"
        return s1
```

When run test cases:

- a = Bag()
- a.insert(3)
- a.insert(5)
- b = Bag()
- b.insert(5)
- b.insert(5)
- b.insert(5)
- print(a+b)

My output is:

{3: 1, 5: 4}

However, the expected output should be:

3:1

5:4

How could I get the right format output? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your `__add__` function returns a normal dict instead of an instance of `Bag`. Instead of that you can use the `new_dict` with a new instance of `Bag` and return it.

```
def __add__(self, other):
    new_dict = other.vals.copy()  # copy required to prevent updating `other.vals`
    for e in self.vals.keys():
        if e in other.vals.keys():
            new_dict[e] += self.vals[e]
        else:
            new_dict[e] = self.vals[e]

    # Create a new instance and populate it with new_dict
    new_instance = Bag()
    new_instance.vals.update(new_dict)
    return new_instance

def __str__(self):
    # Use self.vals here not sef.new_dict
    s1 = ""
    for i in sorted(self.vals.keys()):
        s1 += str(i)+":"+str(self.vals[i])+"\n"
    return s1
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> a + b
<__main__.Bag object at 0x1046c2470>    
>>> print(a + b)
3:1
5:4
```

---

You may also want to checkout bag data-structure([`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)) provided by Python's standard lib for other functionalities possible with it.

Answer (score 3):

Because once you add `a` and `b` you no longer have a `Bag`, just a regular dict.

```
>>> type(a)
__main__.Bag
>>> type(b)
__main__.Bag
>>> type(a+b)
dict
```

If you want addition of Bags to return another Bag, you have to modify your `__add__` function accordingly, such that it returns a `Bag` as opposed to `new_dict`, which is just a regular dict.

Comment: Specifically, `__add__()` returns `new_dict`, which is a plain dict.

Comment: Thank you all for the explaination. Very clear and straight forward.